# LM324 - Issue with output in negative feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier

In my analogue output circuit, the following ripple voltage occurs when wired to the analogue input of a PLC with an input resistance of 69.3 kΩ.

[image: Ripple Issue]

If I put a resistor in series, this ripple disappears.

Why is that? Is it an impedance problem?

The schematic of the circuit is the next:

[image: Output Schematic]

Comment: Probably the load on the op-amp is capacitive enough to cause the amplifier to go unstable.

Comment: You said you put a resistor in series - where in the circuit?

Comment: What is on the load of the U10A? What does the input *and* output signal look like?

Comment: Resistor in serie is put between U10A:1, before the juction with U10A:2, and the load (analogue input of PLC). @Reinderien

Comment: In the load of U10A is connected an analogue PLC input. The signal is an analogue signal generated for a magnetic sensor. @VoltageSpike

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but can your PLC analog input handle a +/- 12 V pulse while the op-amp powers up?

Comment: How do you know the input resistance with that level of precision (69.3 kΩ)?

Comment: Not that it matters but what is the scope vertical scale?

Comment: @PeterMortensen this value is indicated in the datasheet of PLC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The effective load on the op-amp is likely capacitive.  From the LM324 datasheet:

*Capacitive loads which are applied directly to the output of the amplifier reduce the loop stability margin. Values of 50 pF can be accommodated using the worst-case non-inverting unity gain connection. Large closed loop gains or resistive isolation should be used if larger load capacitance must be driven by the amplifier.*

It's not too hard to pick up 50pF of stray capacitance when driving an off-board cable or interconnect.

The fact that a series resistor solves the problem is another clue that supports this.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that putting the resistor in series with the op-amp output *before* the feedback connection can help with capacitive loads. However, this will also tend to increase DC offsets and decrease transient response time.

Answer (score 1):

it's an oscillation proble most probably, I cannot see the sch.
But a good reference for that is this book [https://www.amazon.com/Design-Operational-Amplifiers-Integrated-Circuits/dp/0072320842](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072320842).
There is a chapter dedicated to opamp stability, if you want to know more :)